# Type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to type 'DOMTarget | undefined'

Tags: typescript, gsap

How to fix this typescript error? Sorry i've tried googling/stack overflow but no luck.

> Type 'RefObject' is not assignable to type 'DOMTarget
> | undefined'

```
const leftEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    
useLayoutEffect(() => {
   let tl = gsap.timeline({
        defaults: {
            ease: 'power4.inOut',
            duration: 1.5,
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: leftEl,
            },
        },
  });
}

<div
  ref={leftEl}
>
</div>
```

Comment: [;ease [rpvide reproducible example. I mean minimum repro exmaple

Comment: Thats all the code though?

Comment: `leftEl` is of type `React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>`. You need to use [`.current`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) like `leftEl.current`.

Comment: @yqlim please, consider post your comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a `useRef<T>()` is a `RefObject<T>`. To access the actual value of the ref, you need to use `ref.current`.

So in your case, you are passing `leftEl` directly to `gsap.timeline`. All you need to do is just reference the correct value:

```js
gsap.timeline({
  defaults: {
    ease: 'power4.inOut',
    duration: 1.5,
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: leftEl.current,
    },
  },
})
```